# can cppclean be ran in windows?

Tags: python, c++, pip

So this is probably a very newbie question (which I am) but looking for tools for C++ code I found cppclean, so I follow the instructions on the repository [cppclean](https://github.com/myint/cppclean) but when running cppclean from a cmd terminal I get `cppclean is not recognized as an internal or external command` I guess I am missing some steps apart from doing `pip install cppclean` do I need to compile it or anything like it? I have tried to run it from the cmd and the python terminal. Is it even possible to run cppclean in windows or is it just for unix systems? Sorry if the question is too obvious but I have very little python knowledge.

Comment: Did you do `pip install cppclean`? I usually install everything inside a conda environment to keep the system clean, but it should work anyway.

Comment: Yes I did so...

Comment: Is it in your `PATH`?

Comment: @jabaa I could not find an .exe or anything similar to add in the path, where should I look for it to add it to the path? thx

Comment: You need a Python script with name `cppclean` without extension. It's described [here](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. I still don't understand why so many people think, it's more convenient to make a screenshot, upload it somewhere and post it here instead of a simple copy and paste. You can't search in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Python scripts path, e.g. `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts`, to your system environment `Path` variable. (Replace `USER` with your actual user name and `Python37-32` with your actual Python version). It's described [here](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/)

Comment: I do have done but it does not work yet, I have followed the guide linked, but from what I understood that is to be able to run pip commands which I am able to. My error is not recognizing pip but not recognizing cppclean

Comment: I have a cppclean file with no extension in the following path C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts

Comment: @JesusFernandez Have you added `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts` to your `Path`? The link describes how to add the _"Python application path"_ (for `python` and `pip`) and the _"Python Scripts path"_. That are two different paths. The former contains the Python executables and the latter the scripts for modules that are installed with `pip`.

Comment: I have added the three of them: `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` also `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` and `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts`

Comment: @JesusFernandez What's the content of `cppclean`? It should be a Python file. On a Linux system you can set the executable flag, add a shebang and run a Python file like any other executable. I'm not sure if this is supported on Windows.

Comment: it is a python file I have attached the beginning of it to the original question, but it is longer

Comment: Can you try to run first `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\cppclean` and then `python.exe C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\cppclean`?

Comment: actually there is no python.exe in this path `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0` python.exe is on this path `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`

Comment: @JesusFernandez You mean `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\cppclean` doesn't work but `python.exe C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\cppclean` works?

Comment: @JesusFernandez Does this help: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Comment: thanks for helping, but nothing seems to work I am wondering if needs linux to be executed...

Comment: @JesusFernandez No, Windows supports Python files with shebang. If `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\cppclean` doesn't work there is probably something wrong with your Python installation. This should even work without `Path` variable.

Comment: could it be related to python version (3.9) or not at all?

Comment: I have tried in 2 different computers with different versions of python and I have the same issues, I have uninstall and reinstall python adding it to the path during installation and still cppclean command is not recognized...

Comment: @JesusFernandez If `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe` is the path to your Python interpreter and `C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts\cppclean` is the path to the cppclean script and the above command doesn't run the script there is something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: Did you got to fix this? I had the same issue and in the end I had to execute it with "python cppclean" from within the scripts folder where the cppclean file is.

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this issue also. With the help of aforementioned suggestions, I managed to run it successfully:

1. Open cmd, type in `cd C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts`
   Make sure to replace USER with your username.
2. Type in `python cppclean PATH --verbose`
   (--verbose is optional) (replace PATH with the path of your .cpp files)

After testing it a few times, even though it got rid of declared but undefined functions, it didn't get rid of unused includes.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the above-mentionned procedure worked fine for me, so I was able to run cppclean in a Windows environment.

I used that command successfully :

py cppclean [PATH]